# How to restrict the selection of one Radio Button in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

This is my code to select one item at a time. 
But both the options are getting selected. How can I solve this issue?

```js
function initializehrm__documentidRadiobuttonlist(documentid) {
    debugger
    ajaxCall("/Client/SysType/GetSysTypeByTypeGroupCodeAndSyslevel", { "typeGroupCode": sysTypeGroupCodeEmployeeImmigrationDocument }, "POST", "callback_initializehrm__documentidRadiobuttonlist", documentid);
}
function callback_initializehrm__documentidRadiobuttonlist(data, documentid) {debugger
    data = data.data;
    var hrm__documentidRadiobuttonlisthtml = "";
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        item = removeVirtualObjectPropertiesFromJsonObject(item);
        hrm__documentidRadiobuttonlisthtml += "<div><input type='radio' id='documentid" + index + "' value=" + item.id + " /><span>" + item.title + "</span></div>"
    });

    $("#rdohrm__documentid").html(hrm__documentidRadiobuttonlisthtml);
}
```

Comment: is this `webform` if so, please tag it properly. if it `webform` which one you have used, `RadioButton` or `RadioButtonList`. please provide [mcve] that shows the declaration of the radio button.

Comment: oh right, also set radio button `name` property to restrict only one option selected. i feel this question more of `html` and `javascript`. by your code its unrelated to `c#` sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple radio buttons must share the same name (the value of the **name** attribute), so that it is treated as a group, and only one selection is allowed.

Modify your < input > tag something like below:

```
"<div><input type='radio' id='documentid" + index + "' value=" + item.id + " name='documents' /><span>" + item.title + "</span></div>"
```